# Javascript why return empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, request

I know Js is async but how to prevent my callback from returning an empty array ?
Here is my code :

```
function getPicturesArray(nbr,callback){
    var avatarArr = [];
    for(var i =0; i<nbr ; ++i){
        request("https://randomuser.me/api/",{json: true},(err,response,body)=> {
            avatarArr.push(body.results[0].picture.large);
        });
    }
    callback(avatarArr);
}

getPicturesArray(12, (e)=>{
    console.log(e);
});

console.log('here');
```

And the sout is:
[] 
here

Comment: The `callback` is called immediately, without delay, long before any of the `request`s has been able to call the processing function attached to it, because all those are yet another level of (async) callbacks.

Comment: which request library are you using?

Comment: I use request 2.88.2

Answer (score 0):

Don`t use callbacks. Use Promises or async/await.

```js
  getUserPic = async () => {
    const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/'
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const users = await response.json()

    return users.results[0].picture.large
  }
  ;(async () => {
    const userAvatars = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      userAvatars.push(await getUserPic())
    }
    console.log(userAvatars)
  })()
```

Also try to use this.
In this case I advice you to use Set instead of Array to exclude duplicate items.

```
  getUserPic = async () => {
    const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/'
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const users = await response.json()

    return users.results[0].picture.large
  }

  getMultipleUserPics = async limit => {
    const userAvatars = new Set()
    while (userAvatars.size != limit) {
      userAvatars.add(await getUserPic())
    }

    return userAvatars
  }

  ;(async () => {
    const userPics = await getMultipleUserPics(5)
    console.log(userPics)
  })()
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try !

Answer (score 0):

I'm mocking the calls with a public service for demonstration purposes, but the key point here is the *asynchronous nature of HTTP requests*.

When you invoke `callback(avatarArr);`, your for loop IS done but the (in this case 12) requests you sent are not, so `avatarArr` does not have any items yet.

Notice `async` before `function getPicturesArray`, and `await` before `fetch`

`await` tells the execution to *wait* for the `fetch` call to finish

You MUST check out [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

```js
async function getPicturesArray(nbr,callback){
    var avatarArr = [];
    console.log('loading...');
    for(var i =0; i<nbr ; ++i){
      const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${i+1}`);
      const json = await response.json();
      avatarArr.push(json.title);  
    }
    console.log('done loading...');
    callback(avatarArr);
}

getPicturesArray(12, (e)=>{
    console.log(e);
});

console.log('see how this is executed before done loading...');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will go to bed less stupid :)